# XSS sanitizing nested html tags input

Tags: java, html, security, xss, antisamy

I'm using antisamy library to sanitize input to my application against XSS. I have problem with nested tags like a:

```
<<b>script>alert('xss');<</b>/script>
```

My sanitize method looks like:

```
    public String clean(String input) {
    if (input == null) {
        return null;
    }
    input = StringEscapeUtils.unescapeHtml(input);
    try {
        Policy policy = Policy.getInstance(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/antisamy-textonly-policy.xml"));
        AntiSamy antiSamy = new AntiSamy();
        CleanResults cleanResults = antiSamy.scan(input, policy);
        String cleaned = cleanResults.getCleanHTML();
        return StringEscapeUtils.unescapeHtml(cleaned);
    } catch (PolicyException e) {
         ....
    } catch (ScanException e) {
         ....
    }
}
```

My test against this type of input is failing:

```
    public void doubleTagTest() {
    def cleaned = xss.clean("<<b>script>alert('xss');<</b>/script>");
    assert cleaned.isEmpty();
}
```

With:

> Assertion failed:
> assert cleaned.isEmpty()
> |       |
> |       false
> alert('xss');

```
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper.assertFailed(InvokerHelper.java:386)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.assertFailed(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:658)
```

Do you have any idea how to do handle it without recursive call on `xss.clean()`?

Comment: That second unescapeHtml seems pretty dangerous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Antisamy is producing the correct result - the badly formed tag(s) are removed leaving plain text `alert('xss');`.

Consider the following

`<b<i>>Hello World!</b</i>>`

A bold and italic tag have somehow become muddled - antisamy correctly strips the broken tags leaving the text `Hello World!` which is correct. That there is a plain text that looks like javascript remaining in your original test is of no concern - the harmful `<script>` tag has been removed.